# what causes "Installation Error: Unknown Reason -110" when installing Market applications?

Tags: android

When I install applications from Android Market, I get an Installation error (Unknown reason -110).  I can't seem to find out what this error code means, are there any resources available to look up error codes on Android?

Somebody wrote the code and must know what this error code means, but where can I look to find out the meaning of this or other error codes?

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is rooted and you're using Titanium and you recently use the "freeze" option on some of your system apps, this could cause your error message 110. The solution is to "de-freeze" the system app, reboot your phone and you should be good to go.